# Google Apps Script (Spreadsheet) - selecting an array in spreadsheet based on a condition in cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to select an array from google sheets to create google calendar events based on that. The code chunk below runs just fine and gets the job done. But I want to be able to only select the range that has value of "select" in their column D.
I know it is probably a very easy answer but I am new to JS.

```
function calendarSync() {
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet;
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
// Below instead of selecting the entire range I only need the rows that have a value of "select" in their D cell.
    var eventArray = spreadSheet.getRange("A1:D100").getValues();
    
    for (x=0; x<eventMatrix.length; x++){
      var calEvent = eventArray[x];
      var eventName = calEvent[0]
      var startTime = calEvent[1];
      var endTime = calEvent[2];
      
      eventCal.createEvent(eventName, startTime, endTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet;
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
// Below instead of selecting the entire range I only need the rows that have a value of "select" in their D cell.
    var eventArray = spreadSheet.getRange("A1:D100").getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Please add ()
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
var eventArray = spreadSheet.getRange("A1:D100").getValues().filter(r => r[3] == "select");
```

- By this modification, `eventArray` has the values that `select` is included in the column "D".

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)